# How to update a single document instance by value in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following function which loops through an array of tag strings.

```
static func updateTags(tags:Array<String>){

        let currentUser = User.current

        for tag in tags{
            let ref = Database.database().reference().child("tags").child(currentUser.uid).child(?????)

            let tag = Tag(title: tag,latestThumbnailURL:somethingnew,latestUpdate: now)
            let dict = tag.dictValue
            ref.updateChildValues(dict)
    }
```

For each tag string, I want it to lookup the tag in the db by the tag title, get the tag ID key, and for that specific key, update its values with the new latestThumbnailURL, latestUpdate.

I am stuck as I cannot determine how to lookup a tag ID by the tag title so I cannot form a full ref to the specific tag object. How can I do this?

Comment: First, you are using tag as a variable in your for... loop but then also assigning let tag =...  so that should probably be changed. Secondly we would need to see a snippet of your Firebase structure to see how your data is stored in Firebase - it's unclear if each user have a set of tags that you are trying to load or if it's something else. Your code is also missing either your observe or query Firebase call - can you please include that so we know in what order you are retrieving your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to break you problem up into logical steps!

From how I understand you question, you need to first get the `tag` child objects of your user.

A simple way to do this would be would be to first get all of the children for your user, and then iterate over that data to find your tags with new refs to fetch data from.

```
ref = Database.database().reference().child("tags").child(currentUser.uid)  
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
       print(snapshot.childrenCount) items
       for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
           print(rest.value)
           // Create your new db refs with the tag info
           }
})
```

Alternatively, I'd recommend moving to Firebase's Firestore, which allows for this sort of querying a lot easier.